# Why is ffmpeg removed as part of x11?

Tags: debian, ffmpeg

I've got an embedded device running without monitor, running Debian Jessie. Since I don't need a UI, I considered cleaning up the X11 packages. This gave a somewhat unexpected result:

```
 sudo -u nobody apt-get remove '^x11' -s
```

This produces the following result:

> The following packages will be REMOVED:   ffmpeg libavdevice57
>   libavfilter6 ... libx11-dev libxau-dev ...

The ffmpeg that would be removed is [this version from jessie-backports](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/ffmpeg). That was **not** intended. The `libx11-dev` strictly speaking doesn't match `'^x11'` but I can explain that as an automatically installed package being auto-removed. But `ffmpeg` is manually installed (as confirmed by `apt-mark showmanual`).

What is the link between packages named `^x11` and ffmpeg that causes this?

I've also tried `sudo -u nobody apt-get remove '^vnc' -s` and `sudo -u nobody apt-get autoremove`  Neither affects ffmpeg; it's not some orphan package that gets auto-removed regardless. It is specifically tied to X11.

Comment: To remove X server packages, you should `apt remove ^xorg`, not `^x11`. (Removing some of `^x11` makes sense, but not all of them.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't traced the complete dependency tree, but the linked package has at least the following chain of dependencies: ffmpeg depends on libsdl2, which in turn depends on libxss1, which in turn depends on x11-common.

Since `x11-common` matches `^x11`, it is removed, breaking a dependency of ffmpeg. Thus, ffmpeg has to be removed.  Assuming this is the only such chain, you should be able to keep ffmpeg by ensuring that `x11-common` is not removed.

Comment: How did you trace the dependencies? I can `apt-mark hold x11-common` but that is not sufficient. (I now get a message " The following held packages will be changed")

Comment: @MSalters I traced the dependencies in perhaps the least efficient way possible: by clicking the links on that page. There's probably a way to do it with `apt` but I'm not familiar enough with Debian-based systems to know what it might be

Comment: Ok, makes sense. That SDL library indeed states that it is built with X11 support, and that does explain the X11 dependencies. It's not just `x11-common`, there's a whole list. Sounds like I may need to rebuild SDL for just ALSA.

Comment: The relevant command appears to be `apt-cache depends ffmpeg`. Not `apt-get` but `apt-cache`, and I'm not sure how reliable it is when you deleted the package cache

Comment: @MSalters I wouldn’t bother getting rid of all the X11 dependencies, those are just the libraries (and don’t take up *that* much disk space).

Answer (score -2):

What you're being told is only several ffmpeg libraries are being removed, because no other packages reference them.

If you do this...

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Then do your remove, then these libraries will remain... maybe...

There was a certain time period when ffmpeg was (foolishly) removed from the repositories. Now thankfully it's back.

Depending on exactly what packages you're working with in Jessie will produce different results.

If you move to most recent Ubuntu, you'll have a completely different set of actions occur, because the ffmpeg poser code (my opinion) has been removed now + true/real ffmpeg now delivers again.

With Jessie, as I recall, the poser code was call aconv or something similar, so if you attempted installing ffmpeg at some points you'd either get a message saying to install aconv or ffmpeg might have been a virtual package pointing to aconv. This nonsense was all very confusing, for many years.

Just keep in mind. The APT system knows what it's doing + only removes orphan packages when they no longer have references.

So if a package is flagged for removal, then whatever the reason, the package should be removed (has no references).

Comment: I understand that `libavdevice57 libavfilter6` would be removed, as they are only used by `ffmpeg`. But the `apt-get remove ` starts by removing `ffmpeg`, and that is my problem. I simply cannot find the reason - ffmpeg is _not_ an orphan. It's manually installed, and only automatically installed packages can become orphans. I'm aware of the `avconv` situation, which I linked to the exact jessie-backport version of ffmpeg.

Comment: There is no apt-get remove operation. There is apt-get autoremove, which will remove ffmpeg if ffmpeg was installed as a dependency (like via X11), then the package (like X11) is deinstalled. To have ffmpeg survive continually, you must install it via apt-get install, which will flag the package as being installed directly, rather than as a dependency.

Comment: "There is no apt-get remove operation" ?! [man apt-get](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) disagrees with you. What you call " installed directly" is called "manually installed" by apt, and as the question states that is _not_ sufficient to protect ffmpeg.

Comment: Ah... My apologies... You're correct... I normally use apt-get purge, as apt-get remove leaves config files, which can cause all manner of problems if you happen to reinstall + a new install uses some old config. If you do an apt-remove of X11, the message you received about ffmpeg libraries means, they will be deleted next time you run apt-get autoremove. In other words, these libraries only get deleted when you run a specific autoremove or some tool does this for you. As I said, install the ffmpeg package to preserve ffmpeg libraries.